# Quartz with topshelf. Get jobs from ms sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, quartz.net, topshelf

I have database in MS SQL. I have service with topshelf and quartz.net.
How can I get jobs for quartz.net from database and execute them without restart service?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What kind of jobs do you want to get from the database?

Comment: Quartz supports the persisting of your jobs and triggers in a database. What exactly is you problem and what have you tried?

Comment: I want to get from database cron jobs. For example. In database added row about date and time job. Quartz has to get it from database and create new job to run it at this date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz polls the database periodically and automatically executes pending jobs that is finds. So you only need to have the service running and possibly configure jobs (if required) using another scheduler instance that does not need to be started.